# How to get SimpleLucene.Net to work with Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, lucene, lucene.net

We are using SimpleLucene throughout our application for searching. Everything works fine. We upload our application to azure and it works fine, however, every time I do any changes and have to re-upload to Azure I have to re-create index to make sure it is up-to-date. I want to move my Azure index to Blob storage on azure, however I dont know how to get Azure Lucene Directory working with SimpleLucene. Sample code would be appreciated.

I am building index like this.

```
var path = @"my path to the index";
var indexWriter = new SimpleLucene.Impl.DirectoryIndexWriter(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path), true);
var definitions = GetDefinitions().ToList();

using (var indexService = new SimpleLucene.Impl.IndexService(indexWriter))
{
     try
     {
         indexService.IndexEntities(definitions, new DefinitionsIndexDefinition());
     }
     catch { }
}
```

How can I create indexWriter from Azure blob storage? I know there is AzureDirectory dll that I can use but it doesn't work with SimpleLucene

Comment: This might help http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-Library-for-83562538

Comment: @Blam - I have this library, but I cannot get it working with SimpleLucene

Answer (score 1):

I would say that Simple Lucene may not be a good option to use with Windows Azure because I am not sure if it has code to store the index on Windows Azure Blob Storage. Are you sure it can save to index on Windows Azure Blob storage?

I have used [Lucene.NET for Windows Azure](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-Library-for-83562538), which you can use to store index on Windows Azure Blob storage directly by setting Azure Blob Storage

Step 1: Configure your Azure Blob Storage

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- azure SETTINGS -->
    <add key="BlobStorageEndpoint" value="http://YOURACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net"/>
    <add key="AccountName" value="YOURACCOUNTNAME"/>
    <add key="AccountSharedKey" value="YOURACCOUNTKEY"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Step 2: Use IndexWriter to store index on Azure Blob Storage:

```
AzureDirectory azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory("TestCatalog");
IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(azureDirectory, new StandardAnalyzer(), true);
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Field("id", DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc().ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
doc.Add(new Field("Title", “this is my title”, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
doc.Add(new Field("Body", “This is my body”, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
indexWriter.AddDocument(doc);
indexWriter.Close();
```

So if you decide to use Lucene.net for Windows Azure that would be the comparatively easier and best course of action.

Comment: This code I already have. I had to modify implementation of SimpleLucene to get it working. I think it works, need to do some more tests.

Comment: SimpleLucene is a nice wrapper on top of Lucene.NET, it has 3 downloads on codeplex is only because you dont really download it from there, you get it from NuGet wher eit has 995 downloads.

Comment: got it.. thanks for the info. I have never even tried to use it. May be you can get Lucene.Net working first and then try to use SimpleLucene, that might help you to get going. good luck!!